# Google ajax api

Tags: ajax

Is it possible to use Google AJAX API : 
on local google search engine for example : google.es

or is it only working for google.com?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and there are a few ways to do it.

See [this entry](http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2009/10/web-search-in-your-country.html) on Googles AJAX API blog.

> There are three possible ways to implement, depending on how you're using the API:
>
> 1. If you use the loader, you can simply load jsapi on the domain you're
>      interested in (example), such as:
> 2. Alternately, you can set this with the web search object's
>      .setRestriction method (example):
>
>    var ws = new google.search.WebSearch();
>        ws.setRestriction(google.search.Search.RESTRICT_EXTENDED_ARGS,
>                          {'gl' : 'es'});
> 3. Finally, if you're using the RESTful interface, all you have to do
>      is append a "gl" URL parameter to your
>      request:
>
>    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=flowers&gl=fr

Comment: When I use google.fr to search the keyword "flowers" : 

The first site found is :
www.1800flowers.com

Whereas when it comes to Google AJAX API with the "gl=fr" parameter , the first web site is :
http://www.flowercampings.com

I want Google AJAX API to give me the same order as if i was doing a manual searching.